# TypeError: Unable to get property 'map' of undefined or null reference

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This (https://github.com/sanity-io/example-frontend-next-js) react example works well when I run. But integrating with an existing react (reducer-redux) app. I am getting
`TypeError: Unable to get property 'map' of undefined or null reference`

I think the problem comes from my ReactDOM.render() according to the stack trace on chrome. Any help, please?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in **the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should add some code... From the error message, it's look like you're trying to call map on an undefined variable. If you're using redux, maybe it's because you don't have this variable inthe initialState of your reducer. Without code it's just guess -_-